# Reading from information from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe

I was writing server client model, so i have multiple threading running in parallel so i tried to lock the shared resources and tried to read the dataframe.
But i'm not able to do that.

Here is my **code** which is responsible for reading the dataframe.

```
def get_user_data(user_name):
    global User_base_info
    print(User_base_info)
    Error = False
    Passcode = None
    User_id = None
    try:
        print("in")
        Lock.acquire()
        print("lock", user_name)
        Passcode = User_base_info.loc(user_name, "Passcode")
        User_id = User_base_info.loc(user_name, "User_ID")
        print(Passcode, User_id, "hii")
    except KeyError:
        Error = True
    finally:
        time.sleep(2)
        Lock.release()
        return Passcode, User_id, Error

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    load_base_user_database()
    #print(User_base_info)
    print(get_user_data("RedDragon47"))
```

This the **output** i got

```
            User_ID        Passcode
User_name                          
RedDragon47   47aa4  ...........
in
lock RedDragon47
(None, None, False)
[Finished in 3.9s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .loc accessor is used with indexing rather than as a method call like so:

```py
passcode = User_base_info.loc[user_name, "Passcode"]
#                 ^                     ^
```

However given that you are attempting to get a single value not a series of values, you probably want to use the `at` method instead like so:

```py
passcode = User_base_info.at[user_name, "Passcode"]
```